# SimpleInjector duplicate registrations for RegisterManyForOpenGeneric for implementations with more than one interface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have an issue regarding automatic registration of `IEventHandler<>` with `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` which results in duplicate registrations (something I am doing wrong I am sure).

In my application an event is raised by an external input which is then dispatched to all classes which implement the `IEventHandler<>` of the incoming event type:

```
// during bootstrap, the below code is called
resolver.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventHandler<>), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// when the app is running, an external event is published below:
public void PublishEvent(object evnt)
{
    var handlerType = (typeof(IEventHandler<>)).MakeGenericType(evnt.getType());
    var handlers = resolver.GetAllInstances(handlerType).ToList();

    foreach(var handler in handlers)
    {
        /* do some reflection to get method */
        method.Invoke(handler, new[] { evnt } });
    }
}

// the below is an event handlers that get automatically wired up OK
class TopicVoteStatisticsProjection : IEventHandler<AdminActedOnTopic>
{
    public void Handle(AdminActedOnTopic evnt)
    {
        // for every event, this gets called once and all is good
    }    
}
```

With the above all the `IEventHandler<>` classes are wired up automatically, and all events published via the above code are sent to the handlers OK (for the above scenario where I have the *single* interface `IEventHandler<AdminActedOnTopic>`).

If however I register more than one event handler interface within the same implementation class:

```
class TopicVoteStatisticsProjection : IEventHandler<UserVotedOnTopic>, IEventHandler<AdminActedOnTopic>
{
    public void Handle(UserVotedOnTopic evnt)
    {
    }

    public void Handle(AdminActedOnTopic evnt)
    {
        // for every event, this gets called twice!!
    }
}
```

Then what happens is is the same handler for IEventHandler is returned twice as:

```
handlers = resolver.GetAllInstances(typeof(IEventHandler<AdminActedOnTopic>)).ToList();

/* above query returns the following instances: 
Projections.TopicVoteStatistics.TopicVoteStatisticsProjection
Projections.TopicVoteStatistics.TopicVoteStatisticsProjection
*/
```

This is bad as it doubles up on my calculations! In this case the two events are related and I would ideally like to keep them together in the same handler implementation.

**My question is please - How can I have automatic registration of handlers, some of which that implement more than one `IEventHandler<>` interface, without the duplicate registrations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the behaviour you are seeing is a bug which was introduced in version 2.7. It is described in detail here: https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/20996

It should be fixed from version 2.7.2.

Comment: Maarten is correct. Please update to 2.7.2. We're sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: At least I have some cool statistics and metrics code available now in my mediator code that was used to find this issue :) Still plenty of hair left though so no worries and thanks for the awesome library. 2.7.2 now works fine without any double dispatch